# Paperclip: "has an extension that does not match its content" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am just trying to do some really simple picture uploading using paperclip. I googled this issue and it seems like everyone else has much more complicated problem than simple uploads. Below are my models and controllers.

pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


# validates the description
validates :description, presence: true 
validates :user_id, presence: true
# validates paperclip
validates_attachment :image, presence: true, 
                    content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif"]},
                    size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }


end
```

pin_controller.rb

```
 class PinsController < ApplicationController
    #before_filer will authentiate users to make sure they are logged in before doing anything with the Pins, with the except of indexing the pins so non-logged on users can also see them  
      before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
      before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /pins
      # GET /pins.json
      def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  def new
    # associate @pin to the current user's id
    @pin = current_user.pins.new
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
    # makes sure no other user can mess without a proper user id
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    # associate @pin to current user's id
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    # makes sure no other user can mess without a proper user id
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update(pin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    # makes sure no other user can mess without a proper user id
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

Here are what I think might be wrong with my code.

**First**, I followed the One Month Rails Tutorial, but since I am watching the outdated Rails 3 series, I have to convert everything he teaches into Rails 4 by myself through research. I may have set up the strong parameters wrong in my pin.rb controller. I added **:image** attribute field to the **pin_params** method like so

```
     params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
```

is this the right way to add **:image** using strong parameters? In rails 3, he added **:image** within **attr_accessible**

**Second**, in the README for paperclip, it says I should run **which convert** and ultimately input this line in my config file

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

Since I am using a windows machine, this is what I got ultimately after looking answers for hours

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/"
```

does the above path looks relatively correct for windows?

Answer (score 2):

I too use Windows and was getting this error. I found my answer [here](http://blogs.pigrider.com/blogs/57). From what I gather, Paperclip protects against spoofing by getting the server's OS to validate the file's MIME type. It does this by executing the following command:

```
file -b --mime <my_file_name.extension>
```

The trouble is, the standard Windows Command Line doesn't have the `file` command, so the spoofing check fails and Paperclip throws the error that you observed.

To resolve this issue:

1. Install [File for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).
2. Edit your system's `PATH` variable so that it includes the "File for Windows" `bin` directory path. (For me, it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`.)
3. Restart your Command Line, Git Bash, or what have you because you edited your `PATH` variable.
4. Confirm that Windows Command Line now responds to the `file` command.

This method worked for me on Windows 8.1 with Paperclip 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

In your pin.rb Delete this line

```
validates_attachment :image, presence: true, 
                content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif"]},
                size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
```

Because your already use

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

I also do One More Rails with the outdated videos,like you.
Check for errors from my project
Here is the link [My GigHub Project Files](https://github.com/mikemccallen/twitter)
Good Luck!)